# Find Haskell function if given a result output

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve a beginner problem but can't reach the solution:

Find function `f` where `g f [10,8,6,4,2] == [10,8,6,4]`
and

```
g :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
g f xs = map f (tail (map f xs))
```

How to solve it step by step to develop the right way of thinking?

For solution, my first thought was `reverse` but discarding it immediately as `map` cannot apply `reverse` to each element of the list, it seems nonsense. Next I try to think like this:

```
g f xs = map f (tail (map f xs)) == 
g f xs = map f (tail (map f [10,8,6,4,2])) ==
```

and now I get stuck as I don't see the solution immediately what to apply to each element of this list to get out something that, when `tail` is applied, gives me out something that I can use again for this unknown function and then get out the input list but without `2` in the end. Please kindly help, I feel stupidly stuck.

Comment: Since you don't know `f` but know how `map` works, consider just applying the equations for `map` while keeping the application of `f` as it is. For example, I can rewrite `map f [0]` as `[f 0]`. Successive applications of this rule can get you almost to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue your own computation:

```
g f xs 
= map f (tail (map f [10,8,6,4,2]))
= map f (tail [f 10,f 8,f 6,f 4,f 2])
= map f [f 8,f 6,f 4,f 2]
= [f (f 8),f (f 6),f (f 4),f (f 2)]
```

Can you now see how to find `f` such that

```
[f (f 8),f (f 6),f (f 4),f (f 2)] = [10,8,6,4]
```

?

Comment: f = x+2 is my initial thought now but as map is applied 2 times, then my idea breaks again. Got me through the first map and tail though. Still blind about something here..